# How to use Multiple remote url validation in single field

Tags: php, jquery

I want to check two conditions with remote url on same field but unable to do that.

Here the first condition will be to check the same email id from database along with user cant enter email id with same domain. For example if someone enters demo@gmail.com so first it will check the same email id should not be in the database and if not then it should check that no other email id in database should have gmail as domain name.

My code is like below

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#registration").validate({
        rules: {
            usr_email: {
                required:true,
                email:true,
                remote:"registration.php?fn=check_email&usr_email=usr_email"
            },
            usr_pass: {
                required:true,
                minlength:5
            },
            usr_confirm_pass: {
                required:true,
                minlength:5,
                equalTo: "#usr_pass"
            }                   
        },
         messages: {

     usr_email: {
            required: "Cannot be left Blank !",
            email: "Invalid Email !",
            remote: "This Email cant be used. Plz Try Another one!!!"
     },
      usr_pass: {
            required: "Cannot be left Blank !",
            minlength: "Password must be 5 character long"
     },
     usr_confirm_pass: {
            required: "Cannot be left Blank !",
            minlength: "Password must be 5 character long",
            equalTo: "Passwords do not Match !"
        }
   }

    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: you will need to provide the remote validation function (registration.php?fn=is_exist_record&tb=user&field=usr_email&act=add)

Comment: that function is only returning true or false based on condition..

Comment: well, what if you modify that function to both your checks? and return true/false

Comment: but i want to print diffrent messages based on both conditions..how will i do that?

Comment: how will i pass custom message or if else condition in messages section of jquery validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, if you send back true from your server, the field will pass validation. If you send back a string, the field fails validation and that string becomes your error message. No need to send the same data many times.

In other words, do all the checks in that remote function, and return correct error message if it fails. If you need help with that funciton, you need to provide it.

[Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Ok, try to echo this for error messages (with the extraquotes):

```
echo '"Error message 1"';
```

And try to echo either the word "true" for correct, or a blank string for correct:

```
echo "true";
echo ""; //try one of these rows
```

And then REMOVE the remote:error message in the later part of your Javascript code

Comment: let me chk as per ur comment

Comment: Not working...it is showing the error message in console which i echoed from server side..but not coming as a error in html side

Comment: i m giving php function in which for now i change the database condition with simple if else condition..later on when this will start working i wll change my condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function check_email()
{
    $usr_email=$_REQUEST["usr_email"];

    if($usr_email=='raj@raj.com')
    {
        echo "Error message 1";
    }
    else if($usr_email=='raj1@raj.com')
    {
        echo "Error message 2";
    }
    else
    {
        echo true;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: this is my function @zedd

Comment: Yes working.. Thanks @zedd..the extraquote did the work..Thanks again